# Google Drive API not displaying thumbnail

Tags: html, image, google-drive-api

I have an app that uses the Google Drive API, and I need to display the thumbnails. But when I pass the link to an `<img>` tag it responds with a 404, but if I open the link manually in another tab in my browser it display just fine

Answer (score 3):

- You want to put the thumbnail of the file retrieved from Google Drive to your HTML.

  - The thumbnail link is retrieved by Drive API.
- When you put it and open the HTML, `404` is returned. But when you directly access to the URL of the thumbnail link, you can see the image on your browser.

I believe your goal and your issue like above. For this, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

From your situation, I think that when you directly access to the thumbnail link, you might have logged in Google Account. By this, the image can be seen. And also, I thought that you might have used the following thumbnail link. This is the thumbnail link retrieved by Drive API.

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id={fileId}&v=1&s=###&sz=s220
```

Unfortunately, it seems that this link cannot be directly used at the HTML of outside. So in order to use the thumbnail at the HTML of outside, how about changing the endpoint?

#### Modified endpoint:

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w640&id={fileId}
```

- Please replace `{fileId}` of your file ID.
- `w640` means 640 pixels in the width. If you want to change the height, please use`h` instead of `w`.
- **Please share publicly the file you want to retrieve the thumbnail. It's `On - Anyone with the link`. By this, above link can be used. Please be careful this.**

#### Note:

- When the following HTML is used with the above link, the thumbnail can be seen.

  ```
  <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w640&id={fileId}">
  ```